# AJAX / PHP - How to get posted data to load into a modal on the same page

Tags: php, ajax, post

I'm trying to make a Support ticket system. https://gyazo.com/f87fde8cfacf2165a373f409954cf653 .

For when a checkbox is selected, it selects the users ID (working). But I want to make it so when the green reply button is clicked when they have a user selected, grab their info corresponding to their user id so I can display all the support tickets they have open. And so I can add another reply through the modal. Like so : https://gyazo.com/6fb77589606b1e24160c52885b987624 . But for this example, I'm using a static username fetch . e.g ... FROM support WHERE posted_by = 'Chowderrunnah'. Chowderrunnah is the name of a user.

I want it to get the users id through the selected checkbox (working) and make it grab all the support tickets they have open.

Here is my phpmyadmin database : https://gyazo.com/f9eb86e2877979182f6a2a35cb6ed5df

***Below is my code for what I'm (trying) to do but not working.
Top of page in php tags***

```
function grab_selected_users_support() {
global $con;
global $user_reply_id;
    $username           = $_SESSION['username'];
    $users_support_sql   = "SELECT id, message, posted_by, last_post_by, date_posted, status FROM support WHERE posted_by = 'Chowderrunnah' ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result             = $con->query($users_support_sql) or die("Error");

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            $usersSupport_id            = $row['id'];
            $usersSupport_message       = $row['message'];
            $usersSupport_posted_by     = $row['posted_by'];
            $usersSupport_last_post_by  = $row['last_post_by'];
            $usersSupport_date_posted   = $row['date_posted'];
            $usersSupport_status        = $row['status'];

            ?>

                <div class="well well-sm col-lg-12 pull-left">
                    <span><strong><?php echo $usersSupport_last_post_by ?></strong>: <?php echo $usersSupport_message; ?><br><br><?php echo $usersSupport_status == 'Open' ? '<span class="label label-success">Open</span>' : '<span class="label label-danger">Closed</span>' ?></b><hr><i><?php echo $usersSupport_date_posted; ?></i></span>
                </div>
                <?php ;
        }

}
```

**My PHP checks**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['bulk_delete_submit'])) {
    if(!empty($_POST['checked_id'])) {
        $idArr = $_POST['checked_id'];
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        foreach($idArr as $id) {
            mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM support WHERE id = '$id'");
            echo "<p>".$id ."</p>";
        }
        $_SESSION['success_msg'] = 'Support Ticket have been deleted successfully.';
        header("Location: admin_support.php");
    }

    else { 
        echo '<div class="row" style="color: red; text-align: center; padding-bottom: 20px;"><i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i> You must select atleast one support ticket to delete <i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i></div>';
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['add_reply_submit'])) {
    if(!empty($_POST['checked_id'])) {
        $idArrr = $_POST['checked_id'];
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        foreach($idArrr as $idd) {
            $user_reply_id = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT posted_by FROM support WHERE id = '$idd'");
        }
    }

    else { 
        echo '<div class="row" style="color: red; text-align: center; padding-bottom: 20px;"><i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i> You must select atleast one support ticket to reply to <i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i></div>';
    }
} 

?>
```

**HTML buttons**

```
<form name="bulk_action_form" action="" class="form-inline" method="POST"/>

<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary">
    <i class="fa fa-info"></i>
</button>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="bulk_delete_submit"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>

<button name="add_reply_submit" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myReplyModal">
    <i class="fa fa-reply"></i>
</button>

</div>
</div>

<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table m-0" id="table">

<thead>
<tr style="font-size: 11px;">
<th><input type="checkbox" id="selectall"/></th>
<th class="table-header">Message</th>
<th class="table-header">Posted By</th>
<th class="table-header">Last Post By</th>
<th class="table-header">Date Posted</th>
<th class="table-header">Status</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
foreach($faq as $k=>$v) {
?>
<tr class="table-row" style="text-align: left;" id="no_enter">
<td style="font-size: 11px;"><input type="checkbox" name="checked_id[]" class="checkbox" value="<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>"></td>
<td style="font-size: 11px;" contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'message','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $faq[$k]["message"] != '' ? $faq[$k]["message"] : 'None'; ?></td>
<td style="font-size: 11px;" contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'posted_by','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $faq[$k]["posted_by"] != '' ? $faq[$k]["posted_by"] : 'None'; ?></td>
<td style="font-size: 11px;" contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'last_post_by','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $faq[$k]["last_post_by"] != '' ? $faq[$k]["last_post_by"] : 'None'; ?></td>
<td style="font-size: 11px;" contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'date_posted','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $faq[$k]["date_posted"] != '' ? $faq[$k]["date_posted"] : 'None'; ?></td>
<td style="font-size: 11px;" contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'status','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $faq[$k]["status"] != '' ? ($faq[$k]["status"] == 'Open' ? '<span class="label label-success">Open</span>' : '<span class="label label-danger">Closed</span>') : 'None'; ?></td>
<?php
}
?>

</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

***My modal***

```
        <!-- Reply to ticket modal -->
<div id="myReplyModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">
          <?php grab_selected_users_support(); ?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="text-center p-20">
                        <button class="btn w-sm btn btn-primary waves-effect" type="submit" name="addReply">Save Changes</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn w-sm btn-danger waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are using `<button>` tag in form. May be it generates problem. Change it to `<input>` tag.

Comment: You can improve your question. Please read [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When your code shows your precise problem with nothing extra, you are showing respect to those who volunteer to help you. You can also help, by formatting your code such that it doesn't require scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `<button>` inside your `form`. It can work with javascript but with only php, it will not work with `POST` request. 

You should change your `button` tag to `input` tag.

```
<input type="submit" name="bulk_delete_submit">

<input type="submit" name="add_reply_submit">
```

Its style may be change by adding classes which you have added in your button tags.
 If not then you can change the design of your classes like this.

```
<style>
input[type="submit"]
{
 color:black;
 font-size: 10px;
 padding: 10px;
 }//This style is just an example to show you how to that how to change style of input type submit
</style>
```

Hope it will help you.